# using $http with AngularJS

Tags: http, angularjs

I have the following

```
    angular.module('myApp').factory('dashboard', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        name: function(str){
            return str + ':' + 'works!';

        },
        getFlags : function(){                        
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://dalsapent01:8080/DataService/TestDataService.svc/EventTypes', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'dataType': 'json' } })          
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
             }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               alert(data);
                });
        }

    }

}])
```

when I look in fiddler, I see JSON being returned, but status is always 0. any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: on what browser are you trying this? what's your json?

Comment: IE10, Chrome same result 
JSON from fiddler - [{"EventTypeId":1,"Code":"A","Name":"Absent","Description":"Absent"},{"EventTypeId":2,"Code":"E","Name":"Left Early","Description":"
Left Early"}]

Comment: Which status are you referring to exactly. Status in success or error callback?

Comment: status in error callback

Comment: If the status is always 0, it sounds like the API you're making the HTTP call to is not correctly returning the HTTP status code.

Comment: ResponseHeader in fiddler says HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: If request is successful than there will be no status or data in error callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your server response configuration.
Trying your code in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GmfqtFR1pQlUFiSPjlco), everything works fine.

Comment: I am new to web dev. Any Idea what could be the problem?

Comment: you should check your server configuration and your response: what are you using?

Comment: the wcf dataservice I am connecting to get data is already working (being used in wpf application). I am trying to create a web app and use the same service to get data.

Comment: I have update the plunker with the httpBackend mock provided by Angular. It keep working. I don't know your backend, so I can't help you with it. I think you should open another issue asking help for that.